# How can I use keras to predict on a pretrained model from the VideoCapture of OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, keras, resnet

My code is

```
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')

def read_cam(video_capture):
    if video_capture.isOpened():
        windowName = "yolo"
        cv2.namedWindow(windowName, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.resizeWindow(windowName, 1280, 720)
        cv2.moveWindow(windowName, 0, 0)
        cv2.setWindowTitle(windowName, "Yolo Object Detection")
        while True:
            # Check to see if the user closed the window
            if cv2.getWindowProperty(windowName, 0) < 0:
                break

            ret_val, frame = video_capture.read()
            print(frame)
            frame = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)
            frame = preprocess_input(frame)

            preds = model.predict(frame)
            # print(preds)
            print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0])
```

However, this causes a few errors. First, apparently, it's expecting a different sized array:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (224, 224, 3) but got array with shape (720, 1280, 3)
```

Comment: Resize the image to `(224,224,3)` before predict?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the cv2. resize function to change the frame before calling model.predict as the pretrained model you are using accepts only image of the size 224x224.

```
 frame=cv2.resize(frame,(224,224))
```

Comment: Any way to do this without distorting the image?